# FPS drops in some games to 5-10 frames while hardware not fully used. Some games work perfectly fine

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, performance, gaming, fps

Ryzen 5 2600

GTX 1660 6GB

16GB DDR4

Kingston SSD 256GB

With these specs, I was able to run pretty much any game at 1080p.

Games that won't work properly include Borderlands 3, The Elder Scrolls Online, Days Gone, The Forest, while games like Red Dead Redemption 2, Skyrim SE, Horizon Zero Dawn (same developer and studio as Days Gone) work perfectly fine.

I ran FurMark benchmark test using the FullHD preset, 60-65 FPS, no major temperature spike, everything is working as expected. Ran CPU benchmark and the results matched the expected performance for Ryzen 5 2600.

I also checked the performance in task manager while running Borderlands 3, neither CPU or GPU usage went above 30%, nor did any temperature jump, yet I get 7 FPS in the menu and 1-2 FPS in game.

Tried reinstalling graphics drivers using DDU, tried reinstalling chipset.

This is probably a software-related issue, since not all games are impacted. Is there anything else I could try short of reinstalling the whole operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Windows does not release resources rapidly enough. On some heavy-duty tasks I've found WagnardSoft's [Intelligent Standby List Cleaner, ISLC](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/ISLCw), helpful -- not only for games, but when processing large number of files in some applications.

It's free, minuscule and requires no installation *per se* (you can open the downloaded executable, *ISLC v1.0.2.6.exe*, with 7-Zip to extract the folder).

[image: ISLC size options]

You might want to adjust the list size before you hit the *Start* button.

Let me know if this improves game performance.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't do anything. Some games are working fine right now, resource heavy games like RDR2, and also the resources are not overutilized when the game is running. This has got to be some driver/software issue with Windows.